# How would I add .delegate to this external .autocomplete function?

Tags: jquery

I just learned about .delegate today, and I know I can be used for what I want but I'm not sure how I would add it here.

Each line when added needs to me able to use .autocomplete they all use the same data.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

$('#field1').val("");
$('#field2').val("");
$('#field3').val("");
$('#field4').val("");


$("#field1").autocomplete({
                source: "PRODUCT.ORDER.QUERY.php",
                minLength: 2,
                autoFocus: true,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $('#field1').val(ui.item.field1);
                    $('#field2').val(ui.item.field2);
                    $('#field3').val(ui.item.field3);
                    $('#field4').val(ui.item.field4);

                }
            });
     }); 

</script>

</head>
<body>
<button id="removeAll">Delete All</button>
<button id="addLine">New Line</button>
<hr>
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post" id="orderform">
<table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td>FIELD 1</td>
    <td>FIELD 2</td>
    <td>FIELD 3</td>
    <td>FIELD 4</td>
    <td>QTY</td>
  </tr>
  </table> <hr>

<div id="orderForm">
<table class="orderLine" width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input name="field1" type="text" id="field1" size="15" tabindex="1"></td>
    <td><input name="field2" type="text" id="field2" size="15"></td>
    <td><input name="field3" type="text" id="field3" size="15"></td>
    <td><input name="field4" type="text" id="field4" size="15"></td>
    <td><input name="qty"    type="text" id="qty"    size="15" tabindex="2"></td>
    <td><button class="removeLine">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
<!-- START OF THE JQUERY FUNCTION THAT ADDS THE NEW ORDER LINE -->

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#orderForm").delegate(".removeLine", "click", function () {
    $(this).closest('.orderLine').remove();
});

<!-- This removes all newLine table rows -->
     $("#removeAll").click(function () {
      $('.orderLine').remove();
    });

<!-- ADDS the 'newLine' table rows -->
    $("#addLine").click(function () {

    $('#orderForm').append('<table class="orderLine" width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td><input name="field1" type="text" id="field1" size="15" tabindex="1"></td><td><input name="field2" type="text" id="field2" size="15"></td><td><input name="field3" type="text" id="field3" size="15"></td><td><input name="field4" type="text" id="field4" size="15"></td><td><input name="qty"    type="text" id="qty"    size="15" tabindex="2"></td><td><button class="removeLine">Delete</button></td></tr></table>');
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Working 1/2 wayish. Not I can use the .autocomplete again but its not right. I populates all the fields again.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

$('.field1').val("");
$('.field2').val("");
$('.field3').val("");
$('.field4').val("");

$("body").delegate(".field1:not(:ui-autocomplete)","focus",function(){
  $(this).autocomplete({
                source: "PRODUCT.ORDER.QUERY.php",
                minLength: 2,
                autoFocus: true,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $('.field1').val(ui.item.field1);
                    $('.field2').val(ui.item.field2);
                    $('.field3').val(ui.item.field3);
                    $('.field4').val(ui.item.field4);

                }
            });
     }); 
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<button id="removeAll">Delete All</button>
<button id="addLine">New Line</button>
<hr>
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post" id="orderform">
<table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td>FIELD 1</td>
    <td>FIELD 2</td>
    <td>FIELD 3</td>
    <td>FIELD 4</td>
    <td>QTY</td>
  </tr>
  </table> <hr>

<div id="orderForm">
<table class="orderLine" width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input class="field1" type="text" size="15" tabindex="1"></td>
    <td><input class="field2" type="text" size="15"></td>
    <td><input class="field3" type="text" size="15"></td>
    <td><input class="field4" type="text" size="15"></td>
    <td><input class="qty"    type="text" size="15" tabindex="2"></td>
    <td><button class="removeLine">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
<!-- START OF THE JQUERY FUNCTION THAT ADDS THE NEW ORDER LINE -->

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#orderForm").delegate(".removeLine", "click", function () {
    $(this).closest('.orderLine').remove();
});

<!-- This removes all newLine table rows -->
     $("#removeAll").click(function () {
      $('.orderLine').remove();
    });

<!-- ADDS the 'newLine' table rows -->
    $("#addLine").click(function () {

    $('#orderForm').append('<table class="orderLine" width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td><input class="field1" type="text" size="15" tabindex="1"></td><td><input class="field2" type="text" size="15"></td><td><input class="field3" type="text" size="15"></td><td><input class="field4" type="text" size="15"></td><td><input class="qty"    type="text" size="15" tabindex="2"></td><td><button class="removeLine">Delete</button></td></tr></table>');
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### WORKING EXAMPLE!

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

$('.field1').val("");
$('.field2').val("");
$('.field3').val("");
$('.field4').val("");

$("body").delegate(".field1:not(:ui-autocomplete)","focus",function(){
  $(this).autocomplete({
                source: "PRODUCT.ORDER.QUERY.php",
                minLength: 2,
                autoFocus: true,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $(this).closest('tr').find('.field1').val(ui.item.field1);
                    $(this).closest('tr').find('.field2').val(ui.item.field2);
                    $(this).closest('tr').find('.field3').val(ui.item.field3);
                    $(this).closest('tr').find('.field4').val(ui.item.field4);

                }
            });
     }); 
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<button id="removeAll">Delete All</button>
<button id="addLine">New Line</button>
<hr>
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post" id="orderform">
<table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td>FIELD 1</td>
    <td>FIELD 2</td>
    <td>FIELD 3</td>
    <td>FIELD 4</td>
    <td>QTY</td>
  </tr>
  </table> <hr>

<div id="orderForm">
<table class="orderLine" width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
    <td><input class="field1" type="text" size="15" tabindex="1"></td>
    <td><input class="field2" type="text" size="15"></td>
    <td><input class="field3" type="text" size="15"></td>
    <td><input class="field4" type="text" size="15"></td>
    <td><input class="qty"    type="text" size="15" tabindex="2"></td>
    <td><button class="removeLine">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
<!-- START OF THE JQUERY FUNCTION THAT ADDS THE NEW ORDER LINE -->

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#orderForm").delegate(".removeLine", "click", function () {
    $(this).closest('.orderLine').remove();
});

<!-- This removes all newLine table rows -->
     $("#removeAll").click(function () {
      $('.orderLine').remove();
    });

<!-- ADDS the 'newLine' table rows -->
    $("#addLine").click(function () {

    $('#orderForm').append('<table class="orderLine" width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <tr>    <td><input class="field1" type="text" size="15" tabindex="1"></td>    <td><input class="field2" type="text" size="15"></td>    <td><input class="field3" type="text" size="15"></td>    <td><input class="field4" type="text" size="15"></td>    <td><input class="qty"    type="text" size="15" tabindex="2"></td>    <td><button class="removeLine">Delete</button></td>  </tr></table>');
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first, you can't have more than one element (field) with the same id. If you plan to have more than one row in your table, you can change ids to classes (id="field1" -> class="field1"). Finally, why don't you use a "th" line for the header, and move the "orderline" class to the "tds" (`<td class="orderLine">`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the fields have a class of "field", something like this should work.

```
$("body").delegate(".field:not(:ui-autocomplete)","focus",function(){
  $(this).autocomplete(options);
});
```

Edit: I didn't realize that there was more to the code, so i didn't see the html below. Thank roselan for pointing that out. The duplicate ID issue will definitly be a problem, but the delegate code I posted should be a good starting point to figure out how to dynamically apply a plugin to an element that gets added with ajax. After that you just have to overcome the duplicate id issue.

Edit in response to comment:

This line and similar lines

```
$('.field1').val(ui.item.field1);
```

needs to be

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.field1').val(ui.item.field1);
$(this).closest('tr').find('.field2').val(ui.item.field2);
$(this).closest('tr').find('.field3').val(ui.item.field3);
$(this).closest('tr').find('.field4').val(ui.item.field4);
```

Edit: Adding some optimization:

```
var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
$tr.find('.field1').val(ui.item.field1);
$tr.find('.field2').val(ui.item.field2);
$tr.find('.field3').val(ui.item.field3);
$tr.find('.field4').val(ui.item.field4);
```

Comment: That works good on the "field1". How would I populate the other fields as they are now blank?

Comment: Just apply the same method to access the other three fields and populate them.

Answer (score -1):

I did modify a bit your code. this should work (didn't test it of course ^^)

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="removeAll">Delete All</button>
<button id="addLine">New Line</button>
<hr>
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post" id="orderform">
<div id="orderForm">
<table id="orderTable" width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <th>FIELD 1</th>
        <th>FIELD 2</th>
        <th>FIELD 3</th>
        <th>FIELD 4</th>
        <th>QTY</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="orderLine">
        <td><input name="field1" type="text" class="field field1" size="15" tabindex="1"></td>
        <td><input name="field2" type="text" class="field field2" size="15"></td>
        <td><input name="field3" type="text" class="field field3" size="15"></td>
        <td><input name="field4" type="text" class="field field4" size="15"></td>
        <td><input name="qty"    type="text" id="qty"    size="15" tabindex="2"></td>
        <td><button class="removeLine">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
</div>
</table>
</form>
<!-- START OF THE JQUERY FUNCTION THAT ADDS THE NEW ORDER LINE -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.field').val("");

    /* with this method no need to put the first line in the table, I would use this is the table comme "empty"
    var $newLine = $('
        <tr class="orderLine">
            <td><input name="field1" type="text" class="field field1" size="15" tabindex="1"></td>
            <td><input name="field2" type="text" class="field field2" size="15"></td>
            <td><input name="field3" type="text" class="field field3" size="15"></td>
            <td><input name="field4" type="text" class="field field4" size="15"></td>
            <td><input name="qty"    type="text" id="qty"    size="15" tabindex="2"></td>
            <td><button class="removeLine">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    ');
    $newLine.appendTo('orderTable'); 
    */

    // this method good with first 'td' line in table
    var $newLine = $('#orderTable').children('tr').eq(1).clone();

    // if I remember correctly, autocomplete appends to the body. 
    // hence, no need to reasign it to the "newlines"
    $(".field").autocomplete({
        source: "PRODUCT.ORDER.QUERY.php",
        minLength: 2,
        autoFocus: true,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            /*
            $('.field1', this).val(ui.item.field1);
            $('.field2', this).val(ui.item.field2);
            $('.field3', this).val(ui.item.field3);
            $('.field4', this).val(ui.item.field4);
            */

            for ( var field in ui.item ) {
                $('.'+field, this).val(ui.item[field]); //maybe you have to replace "this" by "event.target"
            }
        }
    });


    $("#orderForm").delegate(".removeLine", "click", function () {
        $(this).closest('.orderLine').remove();
    }); 

    // This removes all newLine table rows
    $("#removeAll").click(function () {
        $('.orderLine').remove();
    });

    //ADDS the 'newLine' table rows
    $("#orderForm").delegate('#addLine', 'click', function () {
        $('#orderForm').append($newLine);
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```