# How to do autocomplete when a value from dropdown is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Hi I am using codeigniter framework. I have a auto fill code like when I enter a id in a text box it retrieves a value from database and fills the remaining text box automatically.
When I type the full id and click somewhere I made to auto-fill with the help of ajax. Now when I select some data from the related data drop down I need to auto fill them. How to do this?
Can someone help me code?
Here is my code where I am got struck.

My **controller** function

```
<?php
class Admin_billing extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('billing_model');
        $this->load->model('client_model');
        $this->load->model('employee_model');
        $this->load->model('products_model');
        $this->load->model('package_model');
        if(!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
            redirect('admin/login');
        }
    }

        public function ticket($id)
    {

        $id=$this->uri->segment(4);

        $data['id']=$this->uri->segment(4);

        $data['main_content'] = 'admin/billing/ticket_page';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  
     }

     public function getdetails()
     {  
        $data_to_search=$_POST['val'];
        $details=array();

        $details['description']=$this->billing_model->get_service_name($data_to_search);
        $details['type']=$this->billing_model->get_service_name($data_to_search);
        $details['cost']=$this->billing_model->get_service_name($data_to_search);
        $details['qty_prch'] = 1;
        $details['qty_used'] = 1;
        $details['price']=$this->billing_model->get_service_pricevalue($data_to_search);
        echo json_encode($details);
     }



}?>
```

This is my controller page `admin_billing.php`. Here I have a `getdetails()` that is called when I enter some value in the text box and click somewhere. When I click somewhere or press tab the value is posted from view to this function with help of ajax.

This is my **model** page.

```
<?php
class billing_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();

    }
    public function get_service_name($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('service');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result[0]['name'];
}

    public function get_service_pricevalue($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('service');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result[0]['price']; 
}

    public function get_service_mins($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('service');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result[0]['mins']; 
}
    public function get_service_price($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('service');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result[0]['price']; 
}
    public function get_service_id($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('service');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result[0]['id']; 
}

}
?>
```

Here in this model page, billing_model.php I have few function which retrieves the value from database. Here I get the id from the controller search for it and get the related content with the help of id.

Here is my **view** page.

I have a function that when onchange action happens get the value from my textbox with name `pid[]` and calls a ajax function `getvalues()`
I have another function `BindControls()` for auto-complete action. When I select some value again I need to pass that value to the ajax function `getvalues()`

```
<html>

<head>

  <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-compat-git.js'></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"></link>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>
var baseurl='<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
$(function() {
    $('#test').on('change', 'input[name="pid[]"]', function() {
        var indexOfTheChangedRow = $(this).closest("tr").index();
        get_values(this.value, indexOfTheChangedRow);
    });
});


function get_values(val,rowIndex)
{
 $.ajax({
    url: baseurl + 'admin/billing/getdetails',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        val: val
    },
    success: function (indexOfTheChangedRow, response) {
        if (response != "") {
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON(response),
                rowToUpdate = $("#test tr:nth-child(" + (indexOfTheChangedRow + 1) + ")");

            // add the changed row as the context to restrict the search for the classes to this one row only
            $('.description', rowToUpdate).val(json.description);
            $('.type', rowToUpdate).val(json.type);
            $('.qty_used', rowToUpdate).val(json.qty_used);
             $('.qty_prch', rowToUpdate).val(json.qty_prch);
             $('.price', rowToUpdate).val(json.price);

        }
    }.bind(window, rowIndex),
    error: function (response) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
}

function displayResult() {
<?php

      $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => '');
      $options_employee = array('' => "Select");
      foreach ($employee as $row)
      {
        $options_employee[$row['first_name']] = $row['first_name'];
      }
    $dropdown = form_dropdown('employee', $options_employee, set_value('employee[]'), 'class="span2"');

      ?>

    var complex = <?php echo json_encode($dropdown); ?>;

    var row = document.getElementById("test").insertRow(-1);
    row.innerHTML = '<td><div>'+complex+'</div></td><td><input type="text" name="start_time[]" value="" style="width:35px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="pid[]" style="width:35px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="description" value="" style="width:145px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="type" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td class="qty_prch"><input type="text" class="qty_prch" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="qty_used" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td class="price"><input type="text" class="price" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" class="discount" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" class="tax" style="width:70px;"/></td><td class="total"><input type="text" value="" class="total" style="width:70px;"/></td>';
}
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').on('mousemove', 'input', sumtotal);
    function sumtotal() {
        var hour = 0;
        var rate = 0;
        var total = 0;
        var subtotal = 0;
        $('#test tbody tr').each(function () {
            hour =  parseNumber($(this).find('.price input').val()); 
            rate = parseNumber($(this).find('.qty_prch input').val());
            subtotal = (hour * rate);
            $(this).find('.total input').val(subtotal);
            total += subtotal;
        });
        $('.Grandtotal input').val(total);
    }
    function parseNumber(n) {
        var f = parseFloat(n); //Convert to float number.
        return isNaN(f) ? 0 : f; //treat invalid input as 0;
    }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
            BindControls();
        });

        function BindControls() {
            var Countries = ['ARGENTINA', 
                'AUSTRALIA', 
                'BRAZIL', 
                'BELARUS', 
                'BHUTAN',
                'CHILE', 
                'CAMBODIA', 
                'CANADA', 
                'CHILE', 
                'DENMARK', 
                'DOMINICA'];

            $('#pid').autocomplete({
                source: Countries,
                autoFocus: true,
                minLength: 0,
                scroll: true
            }).focus(function() {
                $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
            });
        }

</script>

</head>

                <?php

      $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => '');
      $options_employee = array('' => "Select");
      foreach ($employee as $row)
      {
        $options_employee[$row['first_name']] = $row['first_name'];
      }
 echo form_open('admin/billing/ticket_page');
      ?>
            <table id="test">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <td style="width:80px;">employee</td>
            <td style="width:35px;">start time</td>
            <td style="width:35px;">id</td>
            <td style="width:145px;">Description</td>
            <td style="width:45px;">Type</td>
            <td style="width:45px;">Qty prch</td>
            <td style="width:45px;">Qty used</td>
            <td style="width:70px;">Price</td>
            <td style="width:70px;">discount</td>
            <td style="width:70px;">Tax</td>
            <td style="width:70px;">Total</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo form_dropdown('employee', $options_employee, set_value('employee[]'), 'class="span2"');?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="start_time[]" value="" style="width:35px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="pid[]" id="pid" value="" style="width:35px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="description" value="" style="width:145px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="type[]" class="type" style="width:45px;"/></td>
            <td class="qty_prch"><input type="text" name="qty_prch[]" class="qty_prch" style="width:45px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="qty_used[]" class="qty_used" style="width:45px;"/></td>
            <td class="price"><input type="text" name="price[]" class="price" style="width:70px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="discount[]" class="discount" style="width:70px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="tax[]" class="tax" style="width:70px;"/></td>
            <td class="total"><input type="text" name="total[]" class="total" style="width:70px;"/></td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>



            </table>

            <div id="add_row">
        <button type="button" onClick="displayResult()" class="add_r"></button>
                </div>

            <?php echo form_close(); ?>  

             <div id="last_button">
        <input type="button" class="Delete"/>
            <input type="button" class="Edit"/>

  <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/function.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me code? Please give me some solutions.

Comment: Where please are you struggling?  Retrieving information from ajax and updating the page? Or getting the selection/change to trigger? Or is server not getting the request?

Comment: selecting the content from the autocomple and pass that value to getvalues() is the place i am struggling. I dont know how to code for that

Comment: how to pass the selected value? @brianlmerritt can you please help me?

Comment: I am in middle of something but promise to come back in an hour if you can set up a jsfiddle.net or similar test case

Comment: Also this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675069/how-to-get-value-of-selected-item-in-autocomplete

Comment: I will try until you come back thankyou @brianlmerritt

Comment: It works for static row. I tried with the above link you have given me. but once I click add row and click on pid text box i dont get the autocomplete? Can you please help me? @brianlmerritt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90502/discussion-between-brianlmerritt-and-anu).

Answer (score 0):

When you add a row, the `.on('autocompleteselection'...` only works on existing html and not anything generated. You need to add delegation, so go from:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#pid').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
        var indexOfTheChangedRow = $(this).closest("tr").index();
        get_values(ui.item.value, indexOfTheChangedRow);
    });
});
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#pid').on('autocompleteselect', 'tr',function (e, ui) {
        var indexOfTheChangedRow = $(this).closest("tr").index();
        get_values(ui.item.value, indexOfTheChangedRow);
    });
});
```

That way you are delegating the .on to also include table rows added later

Comment: Sorry I dont get any results @brianlmerritt

Comment: OK, so you have other errors. Sorry, but without a working fiddle that access your server side code it isn't possible to go through every bit of your code and make sure it works.  Did you understand the bit about delegation? http://api.jquery.com/on/  and look up the bit about delegation. It may be you need a different selector than tr or it may be that your indexOfTheChangeRow may need to be changed to reflect the fact that the TR is already selected...

Comment: My actual problem is a dynamic textbox is not identified by the autocomplete

Comment: OK, it looks like your problem is not delegating the autocomplete.  To fix that, have a look at this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959622/how-would-i-add-delegate-to-this-external-autocomplete-function